# can't get Meteor slingshot to work

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-slingshot

I am trying to get slingshot to work but having a hard time, I am attaching here the code I have.

The error I get n the console is:

"Exception in delivering result of invoking 'slingshot/uploadRequest': TypeError: Cannot read property 'response' of undefined"

client

```
Template.hello.events({
    'change .uploadFile': function(event, template) {

      event.preventDefault();

var uploader = new Slingshot.Upload("myFileUploads");

uploader.send(document.getElementById('uploadFile').files[0], function (error, downloadUrl) {
  if (error) {
    // Log service detailed response
    console.error('Error uploading', uploader.xhr.response);
    alert (error);
  }
  else{
    console.log("Worked!");
  }

  });
}
});
```

lib

```
Slingshot.fileRestrictions("myFileUploads", {
  allowedFileTypes: ["image/png", "image/jpeg", "image/gif"],
  maxSize: null // 10 MB (use null for unlimited)
});
```

server

```
Slingshot.fileRestrictions("myFileUploads", {
  allowedFileTypes: ["image/png", "image/jpeg", "image/gif"],
  maxSize: null,
});


    Slingshot.createDirective("myFileUploads", Slingshot.S3Storage, {
      AWSAccessKeyId: "my-AWSAccessKeyId",
      AWSSecretAccessKey: "my-AWSSecretAccessKey",
      bucket: "slingshot-trial-2",
      acl: "public-read",

      authorize: function () {
        //Deny uploads if user is not logged in.

        },
      key: function (file) {
        //Store file into a directory by the user's username.
        return file.name;
      }

    });
```

Comment: Did you manage to get it to work?

Answer (score 0):

I saw the same issue and it was due to `xhr` being null - try removing the console error line that references it and I'm assuming you'll start seeing the alert with the actual error message:

```
console.error('Error uploading', uploader.xhr.response);
```

I ended up putting in a check for `xhr` before referencing it and then logging it if it existed.